# Android server-client application connected to arduino client is slow/ laggy

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arduino, android-wifi

I have a Android application that contains both server and client sides. Connected via wifi I have a arduino uno board that sends to the android app data received via CAN. The android app can also send commands to the arduino board.

The server has a main thread that waits for connecting clients and for each one opens up a new thread. Now, because there are alot of messages being sent from CAN, inside the thread for each client there is a new thread that puts all the messages received in a buffer from where they are sent one after another to all the clients or only to one, if the message is private.

The client has 2 threads, one in which it listens from server, and one in which it sends messages to the server.

The messages receive are interpreted and shown in the user interface. I have a custom sliding tab in the MainActivity in which I show things like, heights, pressure, etc.(The app controls a hydraulic suspension system).

My problem is that when the arduino board is connected to the app, even if there are no messages sent between them, it's slow, even the sliding between the tabs is laggy. And because of that, the app eventualy stops responding. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the arduino board becomes slow. And the app becomes slow? Both? `Thanks in advance.`. Bad idea. We expect you to express thanks AFTER you have been helped.

Comment: I wonder how you managed to put all that code in 32KB memory.

Comment: Are all the clients different arduino boards?

Comment: `The server has a main thread that waits for connecting clients `. Those clients are arduino boards?

Comment: `a Android application that contains both server and client sides.`. You did not explain why it needs both.

Comment: 1. They both become slow. And i'll keep that in mind
2. Everything that I said was about the Android app
3. No, one is a arduino board and one is the Android app
4. As I said, one client is the arduino board and another is the android app
5. I needed both because I wanted to have a communication between one Android tablet and the arduino board. It is better to have different apps for server and client?

Comment: Please don't use numbers to answer. Please adapt your post. You know now where what you wrote was unclear. So adapt it. No you did not tell for what you need an Android client. Reread your post and adapt the text so alll becomes clear. How can you talk about `both` when there are at least three involved? And if you write about a client make sure we understand if it is the arduino or an Android app.